# A few Emacs noob questions

Tags: emacs

Sorry if these are obvious answers but I've googled around and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

1. When I have multiple files open in split screen mode using `C-x C-3` how do I close JUST the window I'm currently in and no other?
2. I'm using Ruby and it doesn't seem to auto indent my `def` `end` correctly.. is there a Ruby plugin that will fix this?
3. Is there a command to go to a specific line?
4. How do I interpret ruby from within emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **1. When I have multiple files open in split screen mode using `C-x C-3` how do I close JUST the window I'm currently in and no other?**

To close current view `C-x 0`. (Btw, I think you're referring to `C-x 3`.)

> **2. I'm using Ruby and it doesn't seem to auto indent my `def` `end` correctly.. is there a Ruby plugin that will fix this?**

Have a look at

- [ruby-mode for emacs](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=499764)
- [RubyMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyMode)

> **3. Is there a command to go to a specific line?**

Sure, `M-g g` (or `M-x goto-line`)

> **4. How do I interpret ruby from within emacs?**

Don't know. You could try [rubydebug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html).

Comment: For faster access to M-x goto-line, try M-g M-g.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see C-h b  which will give you key binding for the current-buffer to give you a lot of additional things that you might need.  Once you install any Ruby Mode, you can also use C-h m to see key binding for that specific modes in your current buffer, including ruby mode.

Answer (score 0):

for Q3) in addition you might want to know
    C-h w COMMAND 
will always show you the key binding for a funcion

```
C-h w goto-line RET
goto-line is on M-g g, M-g M-g, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <go-to-line>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Q4) you could start a shell in a buffer, either `M-x eshell` or `M-x shell` and the simply run your script there.

Using the eshell configuration in [1] you can easily switch between the shell and your script source (pressing C-z).

[1] http://www.emacswiki.org/alex/2008-08-19_Emacs_on_Windows